# Standard way to make STL objects threadsafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, thread-safety

I need several STL containers, threadsafe.

Basically I was thinking I just need 2 methods added to each of the STL container objects,

```
.lock()

.unlock()
```

I could also break it into

```
.lockForReading()
.unlockForReading()
.lockForWriting()
.unlockForWriting()
```

The way that would work is any number of locks for parallel reading are acceptable, but if there's a lock for writing then reading AND writing are blocked.

An attempt to lock for writing waits until the lockForReading semaphore drops to 0.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Is how I'm planning on doing this wrong or shortsighted?

Answer (score 6):

The standard way to do this is acquire the lock in a constructor, and release it in the destructor. This is more commonly know as Resource Acquisition Is Initialization, or RAII. I strongly suggest you use this methodology rather than

```
.lock()

.unlock()
```

Which is not exception safe. You can easily forget to unlock the mutex prior to throwing, resulting in a deadlock the next time a lock is attempted.

There are several synchronization types in the Boost.Thread library that will be useful to you, [notably](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) `boost::mutex::scoped_lock.` Rather than add `lock()` and `unlock()` methods to whatever container you wish to access from multiple threads, I suggest you use a `boost:mutex` or equivalent and instantiate a `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` whenever accessing the container.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Diego suggest some changes or provide your own answer. Using RAII to lock mutexes is completely relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: +1.  Anything with acquire/release semantics is well served by the RAII idiom.  @bobobobo:  What you want is not a semaphore, but rather a [R/W lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock).

Comment: @Sam: No, again, RAII has nothing to do. RAII speaks of when and how to lock and release mutexes. He or she is asking what is the method to provide standard thread safety to standard containers. Either adding lock/unlock (undoable) or other means.

Comment: Diego has a point.  If I'm sharing a std::list between threads, (say multiple threads dump info into a single std::list), there is no clear construction/destruction to speak about here

Comment: @bobobobo: Yes, there is- the locking and unlocking of the mutex. Miller is right- RAII should be used in this situation to *ensure* the unlocking of the mutex, if you do choose this route. That is, you would have some kind of `LockObject Lock()`, which would automatically unlock when `LockObject` is destroyed, and not offer an explicit `Unlock()` call.

Comment: Ok, I understand. You don't want a `.lock()` method because something could go awry that prevents calling the `.unlock()` method at the end of the block, but if `.unlock()` is called as a consequence of object destruction of a stack allocated variable then any kind of early return from the function that calls `.lock()` will be guaranteed to free the lock. Good point here.

Comment: @Diego I've edited my answer to clarify that adding methods to a container that lock and unlock a mutex is not the correct approach.

Comment: Good answer, poorly worded =)

Answer (score 6):

This is really kind of bad. External code will not recognize or understand your threading semantics, and the ease of availability of aliases to objects in the containers makes them poor thread-safe interfaces.

Thread-safety occurs at *design* time. You can't solve thread safety by throwing locks at the problem. You solve thread safety by not having two threads writing to the same data at the same time- in the general case, of course. However, it is *not* the responsibility of a specific object to handle thread safety, except direct threading synchronization primitives.

You *can* have concurrent containers, designed to allow concurrent use. However, their interfaces are *vastly* different to what's offered by the Standard containers. Less aliases to objects in the container, for example, and each individual operation is encapsulated.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good.  If reading/writing to these shared queues is relatively infrequent/not performance critical, the avoidance of bugs is much more important to me than anything else -- where are these _concurrent containers_ you speak of?

Comment: @bobobobo: You can find them in Intel's Thread Building Blocks and Microsoft's Parallel Patterns Library- both proprietary. You might be able to find various implementations around using Google, or roll your own based on their publicly-available documentation, if you're brave.

Comment: Well as of now you can [download](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=171) TBB, open source

Comment: @bobobobo: Oh, I thought it was commercial. Then do that, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard way to do this?

No, and there's a reason for that.

> Is how I'm planning on doing this
>   wrong or shortsighted?

It's not necessarily wrong to want to synchronize access to a single container object, but the interface *of the container class* is very often the wrong place to put the synchronization ([like DeadMG says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245052/standard-way-to-make-stl-objects-threadsafe/6245226#6245226): object aliases, etc.).

Personally I think both [TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) and stuff like [concurrent_vector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2010/01/16/concurrent-vector-and-concurrent-queue-explained.aspx) may either be overkill or still the wrong tools for a "simple" synchronization problem.

I find that ofttimes just adding a (private) Lock object (to the class holding the container) and wrapping up the 2 or 3 access patterns to the one container object will suffice and will be much easier to grasp and maintain for others down the road.

Comment: Well, the point of `concurrent_vector` is to not have to worry about synchronization for `push_back` and read operations. Its not overkill. But `concurrent_vector` doesn't have an .erase() method, and if you are going to use `.clear()`, you have to be aware that is not threadsafe.  So its not really as carefree as one might have hoped.

Comment: Also, even if you use `concurrent_vector`, it's more likely than not that you'll still have concurrency issues at a higher level as functions in different threads will still be stepping on each other's toes as they modify the data.  So Martin's design advice is quite good.

Answer (score -1):

[Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245052/standard-way-to-make-stl-objects-threadsafe/6245118#6245118): You don't want a `.lock()` method because something could go awry that prevents calling the `.unlock()` method at the end of the block, but if `.unlock()` is called as a consequence of object destruction of a stack allocated variable then any kind of early return from the function that calls `.lock()` will be guaranteed to free the lock.

[DeadMG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245052/standard-way-to-make-stl-objects-threadsafe/6245226#6245226):
Intel's [Threading Building Blocks](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-tbb/) ([open source](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)) may be what you're looking for.

There's also [Microsoft's concurrent_vector and concurrent_queue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2010/01/16/concurrent-vector-and-concurrent-queue-explained.aspx), which already comes with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Is this meant to be a comment?

Comment: It's meant to be THE ACCEPTED ANSWER!!